# How to get value from textbox dynamically added with javascript - c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I can dynamically add table row with textbox using the code below.

How can I get the value from each textbox added, so that I can send it to my database.

Jsfiddle.net/leftstick/DVEXG

```
var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
        var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var t1=document.createElement("input");
            t1.id = "txtName"+index;
            cell1.appendChild(t1);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var t2=document.createElement("input");
            t2.id = "txtAge"+index;
            cell2.appendChild(t2);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        var t3=document.createElement("input");
            t3.id = "txtGender"+index;
            cell3.appendChild(t3);
        var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
        var t4=document.createElement("input");
            t4.id = "txtOccupation"+index;
            cell4.appendChild(t4);
  index++;

}
```

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough detail. Is this Web Forms? MVC? MVC Core? Nancy? A SPA communicating to Web API?

Comment: If I were to assume this is webforms we're talking about. Then it would be better to add conrols in code behind. Either dynamically or in a Repeater Control.

Comment: @mason It's webform

Comment: try using ajax jquery calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some code like this:

```
var value = Request.Form["txtName1"];
```

Comment: How can this get all the values from each textbox

Comment: @NiangMoore Each textbox should have a name attribute set. Then call `Request.Form` and pass in the appropriate name.